# Behavioral verilog: creating multiple muxes with 1 module

Tags: verilog, mux

If I have a module defined like this:

```
module mux_1x2(in, out, select);
```

and I need 32 of them, I know that using structural coding I can do:

```
mux_1x2 mux01(in[0], out[0], select);
mux_1s2 mux02(in[1], out[1], select); 
etc...
```

But how can I use behavioral programming to make 32 of these in some sort of loop without having to explicitly define each one?

edit: Just for context, I'm trying to make a 2-stage 64-bit carry-select adder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generate block: (IEEE1364-2001 and above)

```
genvar gidx;
generate
  for(gidx=0; gidx<32; gidx=gidx+1) begin : loop
    mux_1x2 mux(in[gidx], out[gidx], select);
  end
endgenerate
```

Or array the instance: (IEEE1364-1995 and above)

```
mux_1x2 mux[0:31] ( .in(in) , .out(out) , .select(select)  );
```

Or parameterize:

```
module mux_1x2 #(parameter WIDTH=1) (input [WIDTH-1:0] in, output [WIDTH-1:0] out, input select);
  // ...
endmodule
// ...
mux_1x2 #(32) mux ( .in(in) , .out(out) , .select(select) );
```

Comment: Oh I forgot I could just do an array of them. What does gidx stand for? Also for the parameterized version does #(parameter WIDTH=1) in the mux module have to be the number of them I'm going to use or should I just keep it exactly like that?

Comment: @Austin `gidx` is just the variable Greg used for the `generate` loop, which just goes through the numbers 0 to 31 (it doesnt really matter what you call it, Greg just made it clear it was a `g`enerate `i`n`d`e`x`). The `#(parameter WIDTH = 1)` is the declaration for the `WIDTH` parameter which is used to widen the number of bits for in the inputs and output of the mux (so you can think of it as the number of 1-bit 2x1 muxes). The `= 1` is just giving the parameter a default value so that if you do not specify it (like Greg did in his instantiation with `#(32)`), it will be a 1-bit wide mux.

Comment: Thanks for adding that comment @Unn . You got it 100%